# Bootstrap 4.3.1 Tooltip not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular8

After upgrading to Angular 8 bootstrap tooltip not working working. It was working fine in Angular 7. 
Bootstrap v4.3.1, jQuery v3.4.1

[image: Console Error]

.html

```
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cricket">
          <img src="assets/img/cricket_icon_b.png" alt="">
        </a>
```

.ts

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

angular.json

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
          "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
          "./node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css",
          "./node_modules/pg-calendar/dist/css/pignose.calendar.min.css",
          "./node_modules/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css",
          "./src/main.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        ],
```